# What is the purpose of including the type in its definition in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm a beginner in haskell and I wonder about the right way to define a new type. Suppose I want to define a Point type. In an imperative language, it's usually the equivalent of:

```
data Point = Int Int
```

However in haskell I usually see definitions such as:

```
data Point = Point Int Int
```

What are the differences and when should each approach be used?

Comment: think of right hand side as the constructor, you need a name to construct a  Point for given two Int's.  It doesn't even need to be the same name.

Comment: so only the latter defines a constructor?

Comment: @dimid The former defines a constructor, too, named `Int`, that takes a single argument of type `Int`. (Perhaps you find this surprising!)

Comment: @DanielWagner I see, and both constructors return a `Point`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In OO languages you can define a class with something like this

```
class Point {
   int x,y;
   Point(int x, int y) {...
}
```

it's similar

```
data Point = ...
```

is the type definition (similar to `class Point` above , and

```
     ...  = Point Int Int
```

is the constructor, you can also define the constructor with a different name, but you need a name regardless.

```
data Point = P Int Int
```

Comment: I see, so naming the constructor as the type is just a convention? (in other languages, e.g. java, this is mandatory)

Comment: that's correct, there is more of course, algebric data types and the power that comes with it, which you'll encounter soon.

Comment: @dimid Yup. You can also write `data Pair = MakePair Int Int`. The difference gets more obvious with multiple constructors or type variables. The *data* and *type* constructors life in different namespaces.

Comment: @dimid To be more specific, the convention is to name the constructor the same as the type if there is only one constructor; if there are more, all of them usually get different names from the type.

Answer (score 3):

The `data` definitions are, ultimately, **tagged** unions. For example:

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
```

Now how would you write this type using your syntax?

Moreover it remains the fact that in Haskell you can *pattern match* over this values and see which constructor was used to build a value. The name of the constructor is needed for pattern matching, and if the type has just one constructor it often re-uses the same name as the type.

For example:

```
let x = someOperationReturningMaybe
in case x of
        Nothing -> 0
        Just y -> y+5
```

This is different from *plain union* type, such as C's `union` where you can say "this thing is etiher an `int` or a `float`" but you have no way to know which one it actually is (except by keeping track of the state by hand).

Writing the code above using a C union you have no way to use a `case` to perform different actions depending on the constructor used, and you have to keep track explicitly what type is contained in that `x` and use an `if`.